# MySQL Stored Procedure Always Selects True

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like so:

```
delimiter //
create procedure UserRole_IsUserAdmin(userID int)
begin
    if userID is null then
        select 'User ID is required.';
    else
        if (
                select 
                    count(UserRoleCode) 
                from 
                    UserRole 
                where 
                    UserID = userID
                    and RoleCode = 1 
                    and VendorCode is null 
                    and NPOCode is null
            ) > 0 then
            select true;
        else
            select false;
        end if;
    end if;
end;
//
```

The subquery in the if statement will return 0 sometimes (for example, when the userID is 5), and 1 sometimes (for example, when the userID is 1). The problem is that the stored procedure always selects true. I haven't been able to figure out why, and it's driving me insane. I don't know if it's something wrong I'm doing in my if statement, or what.

The code calling the procedure:

```
call UserRole_IsUserAdmin(5);
/*Should return false*/
call UserRole_IsUserAdmin(1);
/*Should return true*/
```

As requested, here's the table's data
[image: Sample Data]

UserID is the FK ID of the user, RoleCode is the FK ID of the role the user is in. UserRoleCode is just an auto-incremented PK. The procedure should return true if there is a record where ncode and vcode are null and rolecode is 1.

Comment: It might be better to make this a function which returns true or false.  The tri-state "return" value is a bit awkward, though it looks like it should work.  Maybe the code calling it is an issue?  Let's see that.

Comment: Just updated the question, sorry

Comment: Okay, you have added the calls, but how do you know if it returns false or true?  Where is the code for that.

Comment: I'm just using MySQL Workbench at the moment.

Comment: @Jack have You seen ny answer, is that wrong?

Comment: My apologies, yes that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Your simple data, but for me worked sth. like that.

```
BEGIN
IF userID IS NULL THEN
    SELECT 'User ID is required.';
ELSE
        SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0,TRUE,FALSE) AS if_stmt 
            from 
                UserRole 
            where 
                UserID = userID
                and RoleCode = 1 
                and VendorCode is null 
                and NPOCode is null;

END IF;
END$$
```